# Configuring mm should match in Solr for single clause to 9 clause

Tags: solr, full-text-search

I am using Solr 8, and having issue with mm should match. While the example value 2<-25% 9<-3 works fine.

I am clueless how to do it this way.

**I want to configure search behavior that should work like...**

1. If there are one clause, its required.
2. If there are more than one clause, any one is required (works like OR operator).
3. If there are 3-9 clauses all but 25% are required, and if there are
   more than 9 clauses, all but three are required.

I am unable to find way to configure it like this.

Comment: What is your actual question? Your question text is the description of the example from the manual, and I fail to see an actual question?

Comment: @MatsLindh thanks for point out that. I should be more clear. Also updated question with specific details

Comment: I'm still not parsing your question, though - You say the example value works fine. The description given below is however [the verbatim description of what that example means](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-dismax-query-parser.html#TheDisMaxQueryParser-Themm_MinimumShouldMatch_Parameter). So either it works or it doesn't - if it doesn't, give an example of where it fails with the document and the query you're using.

Comment: Yes, the example works. But I want to change it, and I don't know how to make it do what I want.

Comment: So _what do you want it to do_? What you've typed as the points is _what it does with your example_.

Comment: corrected the question, I didn't noticed that earlier